# Show that the provided functional equation is satisfied for all $x\in (a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

A function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and twice differentiable on $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Prove that for each $x\in (a,b)$, there is some $y\in (a,b)$ s.t $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x-a)(x-b)f''(y)$

Probably we are to use Cauchy's mean value.

Comment: shouldn't it be $\frac12(x-a)(b-x)f''(y)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s define

$$g(t)= f(t)-A(t-a)(t-b)$$

where

$$A=\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)(x-b)}$$

You have $g(a)=g(b)=g(x)=0$. By Rolle’s theorem, it exist $x_a \in (a,x)$ and $x_b \in (x,b)$ such that $g^\prime(x_a)=g^\prime(x_b)=0$. And by Rolle again, one can find $y \in (x_a,x_b)$ such that $g^{\prime \prime}(y)=f^{\prime \prime}(y)-2A= 0$.

Which allows to conclude to the desired result using $A$ definition.